# Find the last 5 apps which got restarted in marathon

Tags: docker, curl, mesos, marathon, dcos

I need a curl command to find the applications and the time which were restarted in the last 30 minutes in mesos marathon.

For example, I hit the curl in the terminal like below:

```
curl http://marathon:5050/............
```

Then the output should be like:

```
APP    TIME_OF_RESTART

app1     2018-07-01 23:45PM IST
```

If I can get the curl command then I can write a script to automate it to provide the details required.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you may want to use the [Marathon Event Bus](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/event-bus.html) which streams all Marathon events.

The parameter you would be interested in is `unhealthy_task_kill_event` if you are looking for tasks that failed health checks enough times and require a "restart".

From the [Marathon REST API documentation](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/1.4/docs/rest-api.html):

> If a task fails more than `maxConsecutiveFailures` health checks consecutively, that task is killed causing Marathon to start more instances. These restarts are modulated like any other failing app by `backoffSeconds`, `backoffFactor` and `maxLaunchDelaySeconds`. The kill of the unhealthy task is signalled via `unhealthy_task_kill_event event`.